# For what values of $x$ does the geometric series $(2+x)+(2+x)^2+(2+x)^3+\cdots$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am stuck on this geometric series question:

For what values of $x$ would the infinite geometric series $(2+x)+(2+x)^2+(2+x)^3+\cdots$ converge?

Formula for series:

$$S_n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$

The first term $a=(2+x)$ and the common ratio $r=(2+x)$ ?

$$S_n=\frac{(2+x)(1-(x+2)^n)}{1-(x+2)}$$

Am I totally wrong on this or somewhat on the right track?

Thanks

Comment: You want $|2 + x| < 1.$ You can solve for $x$ now. You aren't totally wrong, I am guessing you wanted to take the limit from what you have gotten, but I honestly don't find that limit to be very appetizing.

Answer (score 2):

You're right as far as you've taken it.  Now you need to recall that the series converges if $-1<r<1$ and diverges otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy formula for geometric series that says it converges if and only if the ratio $r$ has absolute value less than one.  In this case you want $-1 < 2 + x < 1$, i.e. $-3 < x < -1$.

However, your way works too.  Starting where you left off, we have (for $x \ne -1$)
$$
S_n
= \frac{(2+x)(1-(x+2)^n)}{1-(x+2)}
= \frac{-(2+x)}{1+x}\left(1-(x+2)^n\right)
$$
If $|x + 2| < 1$, then $|x+2|^n \to 0$, so the partial sums converge to $\dfrac{-(2+x)}{1+x}$.
If $|x + 2| > 1$, $|x + 2|^n \to \infty$ and $(2 + x) \ne 0$, so the partial sums diverge.  In the last case $|x + 2| = 1$, we have $x = -1$ or $x = -3$, and you can check that both of these give divergent series.  For $x = -1$ your partial sum formula doesn't work, so you need to look at the series directly.

Answer (score 1):

We determine the convergence of series by several tests. My favorite tests are the following in order: 1) Ratio test 2) Integral test 3) Several comparison tests 4) Root test 5) General term test.

In this question, the series given  is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2+x)^n$ with general term $a_n=(2+x)^n$. Let's apply the ratio test:
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{(2+x)^{n+1}}{(2+x)^n}\right|=|2+x|.$$
For absolute convergence, $L<1\implies |2+x|<1\implies -3<x<-1$. Are we finished checking? No. We must check the boundries! For $x=-1$, the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$ and it is divergent; for $x=-3$, the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ and it is again divergent by general term test. Therefore, the interval of convergence is $$I=(-3,-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite geometric series, so the formula is simply $\frac a{1-r}$. $(2+x)$ needs to be between $-1$ and $1$ for the series to converge, so $x$ needs to be between $-3$ and $-1$ for the series to converge.